# Function in kotlin return value before ends Fuel.post

Tags: android, kotlin, httpresponse

I have a function with Fuel.post that returns a value before Fuel.post ending, this is the code...

```
var res = rs.requestLogin("user", "password")
```

and my function

```
fun requestLogin(user : String, pass : String) : String {
  var res = ""
    val _params = HashMap<String, String>()

    _params.put("user", user)
    _params.put("pass", pass)

    Fuel.post(Constantes.ENDPOINT_LOGIN, _params.toList())
            .responseString(Charset.forName("UTF8")){ request, response, result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Result.Success -> {
                        res = "0"
                    }

                    is Result.Failure ->{
                        res = "-1"
                    }
                }
            }
    return res
}
```

I use this lib: https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel
How i can return res value at Fuel.post ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently you are using the async version of that call. By passing that lambda to `responseString()`, you are telling it you want that code to handle the response if and when it comes back at some point in the future, asynchronously.

I suspect if you use the [blocking version](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#blocking-mode), you might get the result you are after.

Totally untried code:

```
val (request, response, result) = Fuel.post(Constantes.ENDPOINT_LOGIN, _params.toList())
    .responseString()
return if(result == Result.Success) "0" else "-1"
```